# Error when using Cucumber for Android - Unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jvm, cucumber

I wanted to write Kotlin tests using Cucumber, however something does not seem to work.
I keep on getting `Unsupported class file major version 63` error despite checking out several solutions posted on Stack Overflow and none of them have worked.

I tried changing both JVM and gradle versions as well as them both at the same time and I cannot find any solutions.

Error occurs when launching any feature or scenario test. These are the dependencies I tried using so far:
`implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.12.1'`

`implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.12.1'`

These are the two errors that show up:
`> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Failed to transform cucumber-core-7.12.1.jar (io.cucumber:cucumber-core:7.12.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\mateu.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.cucumber\cucumber-core\7.12.1\179d500a20d2c4d9c387d682586c31bed662d960\cucumber-core-7.12.1.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mateu.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.cucumber\cucumber-core\7.12.1\179d500a20d2c4d9c387d682586c31bed662d960\cucumber-core-7.12.1.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 63. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> `

`Unsupported class file major version 63`

I would be very grateful for any input and pointing out my possible oversights.

Comment: class file version 63 = Java 19. It is pretty unusual for a library to require a non-LTS Java like 19.